# Convert a small dataset written in SPSS to CSV

Tags: r, dataframe, csv, tidyverse, spss

I have a small dataset written in SPSS syntax which comes from [**Table 5.3 p. 189 of this book**](http://docshare02.docshare.tips/files/31719/317194846.pdf) (*type `210` in the page slot to see the table*).

I was wondering if there might be a way to convert this data to `.csv` file? (I want to use the data in `R` afterwards)

```
# SPSS Code:

DATA LIST FREE/gpid anx socskls assert.
BEGIN DATA.
1 5 3 3     1 5 4 3     1 4 5 4     1 4 5 4
1 3 5 5     1 4 5 4     1 4 5 5     1 4 4 4
1 5 4 3     1 5 4 3     1 4 4 4
2 6 2 1     2 6 2 2     2 5 2 3     2 6 2 2
2 4 4 4     2 7 1 1     2 5 4 3     2 5 2 3
2 5 3 3     2 5 4 3     2 6 2 3
3 4 4 4     3 4 3 3     3 4 4 4     3 4 5 5
3 4 5 5     3 4 4 4     3 4 5 4     3 4 6 5
3 4 4 4     3 5 3 3     3 4 4 4
END DATA.
```

EDIT - in order to check answers I am adding here the actual way the data looks after reading it in SPSS :

```
gpid   anx  socskls   assert
1       5       3       3
1       5       4       3
1       4       5       4
1       4       5       4
1       3       5       5
1       4       5       4
1       4       5       5
1       4       4       4
1       5       4       3
1       5       4       3
1       4       4       4
2       6       2       1
2       6       2       2
2       5       2       3
2       6       2       2
2       4       4       4
2       7       1       1
2       5       4       3
2       5       2       3
2       5       3       3
2       5       4       3
2       6       2       3
3       4       4       4
3       4       3       3
3       4       4       4
3       4       5       5
3       4       5       5
3       4       4       4
3       4       5       4
3       4       6       5
3       4       4       4
3       5       3       3
3       4       4       4
```

Comment: Text editing tools like `notepad++` have a column select type feature, which would make cutting and pasting the data from 4 groups of columns into 1 group. then `reader::read_table` could take it the rest of the way.

Comment: Dear Eli-k, can you also replicate the SPSS manova table provided on [page 191 of that book](http://docshare02.docshare.tips/files/31719/317194846.pdf)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the 1st, 5th, 9th, and 13th column of the dataset belong to variable `gpid`, the 2nd, 6th, 10th, and 14th column belong to variable `anx`, and so on. So, we need to

- reshape from wide to long format
- with multiple measure variables
- where each measure variable spans several columns
- and where some values are missing.

Many roads lead to Rome.

This is what I would do using my favourite tools. In particular, this approach uses the feature of `data.table::melt()` to reshape multiple measure columns simultaneously. There is no manual cleanup of the data section in a text editor required.

The resulting dataset `result` can be used directly afterwards in any subsequent `R` code as requested by the OP. There is no need to take a detour using a `.csv` file (However, feel free to save `result` as a `.csv` file).

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)
cols <- c("gpid", "anx", "socskls", "assert")
raw <- fread(text = "
1 5 3 3     1 5 4 3     1 4 5 4     1 4 5 4
1 3 5 5     1 4 5 4     1 4 5 5     1 4 4 4
1 5 4 3     1 5 4 3     1 4 4 4
2 6 2 1     2 6 2 2     2 5 2 3     2 6 2 2
2 4 4 4     2 7 1 1     2 5 4 3     2 5 2 3
2 5 3 3     2 5 4 3     2 6 2 3
3 4 4 4     3 4 3 3     3 4 4 4     3 4 5 5
3 4 5 5     3 4 4 4     3 4 5 4     3 4 6 5
3 4 4 4     3 5 3 3     3 4 4 4",
fill = TRUE)
mv <- colnames(raw) %>% 
  matrix(ncol = 4L, byrow = TRUE) %>% 
  as.data.table() %>% 
  setnames(new = cols)
result <- melt(raw, measure.vars = mv, na.rm = TRUE)[
  order(rowid(variable))][
    , variable := NULL]
result
```

> ```
>     gpid anx socskls assert
>  1:    1   5       3      3
>  2:    1   5       4      3
>  3:    1   4       5      4
>  4:    1   4       5      4
>  5:    1   3       5      5
>  6:    1   4       5      4
>  7:    1   4       5      5
>  8:    1   4       4      4
>  9:    1   5       4      3
> 10:    1   5       4      3
> 11:    1   4       4      4
> 12:    2   6       2      1
> 13:    2   6       2      2
> 14:    2   5       2      3
> 15:    2   6       2      2
> 16:    2   4       4      4
> 17:    2   7       1      1
> 18:    2   5       4      3
> 19:    2   5       2      3
> 20:    2   5       3      3
> 21:    2   5       4      3
> 22:    2   6       2      3
> 23:    3   4       4      4
> 24:    3   4       3      3
> 25:    3   4       4      4
> 26:    3   4       5      5
> 27:    3   4       5      5
> 28:    3   4       4      4
> 29:    3   4       5      4
> 30:    3   4       6      5
> 31:    3   4       4      4
> 32:    3   5       3      3
> 33:    3   4       4      4
>     gpid anx socskls assert
> ```

### Some explanations

`fread()` returns a data.table `raw` with default column names `V1`, `V2`, ... `V16` and with missing values filled with `NA`

`mv` is a data.table which indicates which columns of `raw` belong to each target variable:

```
mv
```

> ```
>    gpid anx socskls assert
> 1:   V1  V2      V3     V4
> 2:   V5  V6      V7     V8
> 3:   V9 V10     V11    V12
> 4:  V13 V14     V15    V16
> ```

This informations is used by `melt()`. `melt()` also removes rows with missing values from the resulting long format.

After reshaping, the rows are ordered by the variable number but need to be reordered in the original row order by using `rowid(variable)`. Finally, the `variable` column is removed.

### EDIT: Improved version

Giving a second thought, here is a streamlined version of the code which skips the creation of `mv` and uses `data.table` *chaining*:

```
library(data.table)
cols <- c("gpid", "anx", "socskls", "assert")
result <- fread(
  text = "
1 5 3 3     1 5 4 3     1 4 5 4     1 4 5 4
1 3 5 5     1 4 5 4     1 4 5 5     1 4 4 4
1 5 4 3     1 5 4 3     1 4 4 4
2 6 2 1     2 6 2 2     2 5 2 3     2 6 2 2
2 4 4 4     2 7 1 1     2 5 4 3     2 5 2 3
2 5 3 3     2 5 4 3     2 6 2 3
3 4 4 4     3 4 3 3     3 4 4 4     3 4 5 5
3 4 5 5     3 4 4 4     3 4 5 4     3 4 6 5
3 4 4 4     3 5 3 3     3 4 4 4",
  fill = TRUE, col.names = rep(cols, 4L))[
    , melt(.SD, measure.vars = patterns(cols), value.name = cols, na.rm = TRUE)][
      order(rowid(variable))][
        , variable := NULL][]
result
```

Here, the columns are renamed within the call to `fread()`. In this case, duplicated column names are desirable (as opposed to the usual use case) because the `patterns()` function in the subsequent call to `melt()` use the duplicated column names to combine the columns which belong to one measure variable.

Answer (score 1):

This requires some manual clean-up in Notepad or similar to place the data in the right format. But essentially, this could be imported using the following

```
df <- data.frame(
  gpid = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,
                 2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  anx = c(5,5,4,4,3,4,4,4,5,5,4,6,6,5,6,
                 4,7,5,5,5,5,6,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,4),
  socskls = c(3,4,5,5,5,5,5,4,4,4,4,2,2,2,2,
                 4,1,4,2,3,4,2,4,3,4,5,5,4,5,6,4,3,4),
  assert = c(3,3,4,4,5,4,5,4,3,3,4,1,2,3,2,
                 4,1,3,3,3,3,3,4,3,4,5,5,4,4,5,4,3,4)
)

write.csv(df, "df.csv", row.names = F)
```

Note that the first 4 values (1, 5, 3, 3) are the gpid, anx, socskls, and assert values for row 1. Whereas the values 1, 5, 4, 3 which appear to be in the next column of the pasted data in SPSS syntax (i.e. the next 4 values reading the syntax left to right) are actually the values for participant 10.

Note: I'm assuming you don't have SPSS installed. If you did the easiest option would using SPSS syntax to create the dataset in SPSS and then just export to R.

Answer (score 1):

Using `readLines` and some string manipulating tools.

```
tmp <- readLines("spss1.txt")  ## read from .txt
tmp <- trimws(gsub("[A-Z/.]", "", tmp))  ## remove caps and specials
nm <- strsplit(tmp[[1]], " ")[[1]]  ## split names
tmp <- unlist(strsplit(tmp[3:11], "\\s{2,}") )  ## split data blocks
```

Finally, splitting at the spaces gives the result.

```
dat <- setNames(
  type.convert(do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(tmp, "\\s"))), 
  nm)
```

### Result

```
dat
#    gpid anx socskls assert
# 1     1   5       3      3
# 2     1   5       4      3
# 3     1   4       5      4
# 4     1   4       5      4
# 5     1   3       5      5
# 6     1   4       5      4
# 7     1   4       5      5
# 8     1   4       4      4
# 9     1   5       4      3
# 10    1   5       4      3
# 11    1   4       4      4
# 12    2   6       2      1
# 13    2   6       2      2
# 14    2   5       2      3
# 15    2   6       2      2
# 16    2   4       4      4
# 17    2   7       1      1
# 18    2   5       4      3
# 19    2   5       2      3
# 20    2   5       3      3
# 21    2   5       4      3
# 22    2   6       2      3
# 23    3   4       4      4
# 24    3   4       3      3
# 25    3   4       4      4
# 26    3   4       5      5
# 27    3   4       5      5
# 28    3   4       4      4
# 29    3   4       5      4
# 30    3   4       6      5
# 31    3   4       4      4
# 32    3   5       3      3
# 33    3   4       4      4
```

**Note:** Results in the same Wilks' lambda as *@emily-kothe*'s method. Maybe the authors used different data or your manova method is flawed?